# Getting connection reset by peer error while using docker on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I am installed docker on ubuntu 14.04 LTS and started docker service but while pulling image for ubuntu or running some example shown in user guide I am getting error .

```
$sudo docker run ubuntu:14.04 /bin/echo 'Hello world'
Unable to find image 'ubuntu:14.04' locally
Pulling repository ubuntu
FATA[0002] Get https://index.docker.io/v1/repositories/library/ubuntu/images: read tcp 162.242.195.84:443: connection reset by peer
```

Thanks In advance

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this by installing the latest docker from maintained ubuntu packages.

Steps:

1. Ensure host’s APT can handle https downloads. This should exists

   ```
   /usr/lib/apt/methods/https
   ```
2. Add the Docker repository to your host’s key chain.

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys 36A1D7869245C8950F966E92D8576A8BA88D21E9
   ```
3. Add the docker repository to your hosts APT sources list.

   ```
   sudo sh -c "echo deb https://get.docker.com/ubuntu docker main\
   > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list"
   ```
4. Update APT.

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
5. Install dcoker.

   ```
   sudo apt-get install lxc-docker
   ```

Referenced this blog post:
http://buildvirtual.net/docker-installing-docker-on-ubuntu-trusty-14-04/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10232022)

Comment: Thanks @jezreal will do